# 正規表現について

Tags: 正規表現

```
  li id="result_0" data-hoge="4592105095" class="s-result-item"
```

```
4592105095
```

answerがこうなるようにしたい
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: HTML だったらDOMで、属性`data-hoge`の値を取り出せると思いますが。

Answer (score 1):

言語の指定がなかったため、JavaScriptを使って回答いたします（他言語でも表現が異なるだけで同様の考え方となります）。

```
var regexp = new RegExp('data-hoge="(.*?)"');
var result = regexp.exec('li id="result_0" data-hoge="4592105095" class="s-result-item"');
alert(result[1]);
```

マッチした値を取り出すために()を使います。()で囲んだ値はその()の個数分、結果の配列に1から順に入っていきます。今回は1つだけなのでインデックス1に入っています。

また正規表現の最短一致を使う必要があります。そのために(.*?)の?をつけています。?がないと、`4592105095" class="s-result-item`という結果となります。これは最後の「"」まで一致させてしまうためです。?を使うことで表現に最短で一致するものにマッチさせることができます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
今勉強中なのですが、phpで書いた場合どういう書き方になるのでしょうか？
返答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: PHPだと`preg_match('/data-hoge="(.*?)"/', 'li id="result_0" data-hoge="4592105095" class="s-result-item"', $m);`ではないでしょうか。

結果は以下の通りとなります。
$m[0] -> data-hoge="4592105095"
$m[1] -> 4592105095

Answer (score 1):

正規表現使った置換ですかね？
検索文字列`data-hoge="(.*?)"`
置換文字列`$1`
でも良いし、単純に数字をhitさせたいのであれば、`(?<=data-hoge=").*?(?=")`とかですかね。

Answer (score 1):

PHP でDOM を使う方法

```
<?php
$src = 'li id="result_0" data-hoge="4592105095" class="s-result-item"';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<html><body><" . $src . "/></body></html>");#厳密でなくて良いｗ
$answer = $dom->getElementById('result_0')->getAttribute('data-hoge');
echo $answer;
?>
```